# Can anyone help me understanding this integral solution?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, approximation, quadrature, chebyshev-function

I was reading a research article in which authors used Chebyshev-Gauss Quadrature on an integral which is given as in the attached image. Can anyone help me out with any citation to understand how $B_4$ and $B_5$ are evaluated?

Thanks!

[image: Chebyshev-Gauss Quadrature]

Answer (score 1):

First, convert your integral limits by using the following method, $$\int_a^bf(x)\,\Bbb dx = \frac{b-a}{2}\int_{-1}^1f\bigg(\frac{b-a}{2}x+\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)\,\Bbb dx.$$ Then using this [link](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1281438499) you can apply Chebyshev-Gauss Quadrature to find the values of $B_4$ and $B_5$.